# node doesn't work after running rosrun

Tags: ros, data, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a package named robot_localizaton offered by ROS downloaded from github.Here's the problem: I put a couple lines of code to export position data,it goes like this:

"cout<<"robot's y position: "<<filteredposition.pose.pose.position.y<<endl;"< p="">

but I didn't get desired output in the terminal after rosrun robot_localization ekf_localization_node(already get params loaded).I assume the node doesn't operate at all. What confuses me most is that running rostopic echo /odomfiltered leads to data stream output. Any answer would be appreciated,thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260824/node-doesn%27t-work-after-running-rosrun/) by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First : verify that the navigation node give you an output. If the node is not initialized or is missing data input, you will have no output.

Then you should use ROS logging system, it is much better to use as it is synchronized so you don't have thread printing issues and it serialize your ROS objects.

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM("hey :" << filteredposition);
```

---

Originally posted by [AlexisTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/29858/alexistm/) with karma: 31 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on 2017-05-02**:
That's impressive.Would you share me a link of ROS_INFO_STREAM?I want to delve int the usage of it.THX a lot